# session variable cannot be access inside a dynamic javascript file

Tags: php, javascript, session, dynamic, session-variables

I know the my question is weird , but it is my situation. I am calling a **javascript** with

`<script src="js/jscript.php"></script>`

And in the other hand i am writing javascript inside jscript.php

```
<?php 
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
header("Content-Type: text/javascript");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>$(document).ready(function(){
....
....
....
alert('hello world!');//all my javascript stuff

<?php
echo $_SESSION['user_id'];  //echo nothing
echo $_SESSION['user_email']; //echo nothing
?>

});
```

And then i tested with my browser , file calling and those call like `alert('hello world!')` have no problem but until i try to **access session variable from jscript.php** , its all empty ... I did set those variable correctly

Comment: Please let me know if i can use better term

Comment: you are not saying `session_start()` at the beginning of the jscript.php file.

Comment: Please check if cookies are sent. Also check that `session.auto_start` in enabled in your `php.ini` or call `session_start()` as @mohkhan sugested.

Comment: Guys thanks for pointing out the session_start() , now i have to call session_start again because the jscript.php are called with <scrip></script> , its worked perfectly now , thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a session start a very start of jscript.php solved my problem

```
session_start();
```

hope its help others.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that can work.

I think a better way would be making an ajax call to a PHP page, getting back the data in whatever form you want (json, or just echo $var ...) and then do something with it.

ex with jquery:

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: 'mypage.php',
    }).done(function(msg) {
          // Do something with msg here
    });
</script>
```

and mypage.php could be like :

```
<?php

$response = array();
$response['user_id'] = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$response['user_email'] = $_SESSION['user_email'];
echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

When the ajax call is made, the php page will create an array, fill it with the session variables you need and return it to your script in a json form with json_encode.
You get it as a var in .done method and do whatever you need with it.